/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
I have a github action (someone else made it, and pretty sure it works in the past)
jobs:
  # some other job/steps...
  upload-binary-to-s3:
    if: startsWith(github.ref_name, 'xx-vault-plugin_')
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: functional-tests
    container:
      image: amazon/aws-cli
    steps:
      - name: set env
        run: |
          echo "TAG=${GITHUB_REF_NAME#xx-vault-plugin_}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
      - name: Download binary
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: xx-vault-plugin-binary
          path: ./plugins


got me:
/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)

Help me understand what needs to be changed, is it the runner's problem or what?

Have you got node v20 setup on your self hosted?
